# SQL: Exporting and then importing data to new schema

Tags: mysql, sql, data-migration

I'm trying to figure out which way is the best way to export a database table and then import it into the NEW columns that have been created in a totally separate database.

Some columns will no longer be used, others have different naming conventions, etc.

What is recommended for this approach? Any online tools?

Again, the new database tables are NOT the same ... I basically need to be able to assign old column to new columns.

Comment: For a single table?  Create the new table, use `INSERT ... SELECT FROM old_table`, and delete the old table

Comment: Ha, yeah ... no it's a little more complicated than that. Completely different databases, different column structure.

Comment: Different as in different host?  Then you need mysqldump.  Otherwise, specify the database before the table IE: `database_name.new_table`, etc

Comment: So far exporting a CSV and converting it within Excel seems to be the best solution ...

Comment: Or you could mysqldump, setup the db on the other host, and use the INSERT statement...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FEDERATED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/federated-storage-engine.html) storage engine to access the remote MySQL instance, then use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) to copy over the data.

If this is a one-off exercise which does not require the servers to establish such a link, then exporting the data to a format like TSV (e.g. using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [*`mysqldump`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html))  and then reimporting at the other end (e.g. using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) or [*`mysqlimport`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html)) would be a sensible solution.

Both approaches enable you to reassign column names (and perform other conversions) as part of the process:

```
-- federated table approach
INSERT INTO localtable (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT colX, CONCAT('foo', colY), 100 + colZ FROM remotetable;

-- TSV approach
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file' INTO TABLE localtable (colA, @colY, @colZ)
SET colB = CONCAT('foo', @colY), colC = 100 + @colZ;
```